# Reference request: a basic result regarding dimension of intersection of algbaric set and hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I know that the following result is true but I need to reference it. I just can't find a source which I can reference. I was wondering if someone could point me to a source I can reference. Thank you very much!

Let $V$ be an affine algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$. Let $F \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. Let $V(F)$ be the vanishing set of $F$. 
Then we have that
$\dim (V \cap V(F)) = \dim V - 1$  if $V \cap V(F) \not = \emptyset$ and $V \cap V(F) \not = V$.

Comment: This seems like Theorem 3.42, pg. 75-76 of Milne's Algebraic Geometry notes: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf

Comment: This is also Exercise I.1.8 in Hartshorne. It follows more or less from the Hauptidealsatz.

Comment: I also wanted to mention that actually you need a slightly stronger hypothesis on V for your statement to be correct: for example you could require that each component of $V$ have the same dimension. Otherwise you can come up with sneaky examples like the following: in $\mathbf A^3$ let $V=V_1 \cup V_2$ where $V_1$ is the plane $z=0$ and $V_1$ is the line $x=y=0$. Now let $F=z=1$. Then $V$ has dimension 2, but $V \cap V(F)$ has dimension 0.

Comment: In the previous comment, I meant to wrie $F=z-1$.